# Why is the "zero sign" in the limit's result not explicit?

Tags: limits

In the property:$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{c}{x^n} = 0, c \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I don't understand why when $x\to -\infty $ is $0$ instead of something like $-0$. That is to say, the function approaches $0$ infinitely, but still negative.

Similarly, when we have perpendicular asymptotes, per example $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{-0} = -\infty$

I think that make the sign explicit is important information, since it tells us about its graph:

[image]

Comment: It's because it's approaching $0$ to the left (the 'negative side')

Comment: One could imagine a world where we used a notation like $-0$ (or $+0$) in this context. But we haven't adopted that convention: we would just say in words "$c/x^n\to0$ from below as $x\to-\infty$".

Comment: By the way, notice that your graph and deductions are correct when $n$ is odd, but not when $n$ is even!

Comment: Because the limit (which is *not* nesc any actual value that the function itself ever achieves) *has* an actual value.  That value is $0$.   And $-0 = 0$.  When we say $\lim f(x) = 0$ we are *NOT* saying the *function* is something weird that is like a number but not really a number and that is like $0$ from the left side.  We are saying the *LIMIT* of the function has a specific and real value that *IS* a number, not something like a number, but an actual honest to god count on your fingers and stub your toe *NUMBER*.  ANd that number is $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, with $n$ even $f(x)$ is always positive

Comment: If the limit of a function is $0$ then this fact itself can not be used to conclude whether the function remains positive or negative in the limiting process. In case of limit being zero, the sign of function values needs to be specified separately (and is considered a separate independent information). And number $0$ is usually written without any sign as it is neither positive nor negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard notation to indicate that the limit of some $f(x)$ for $x \rightarrow x_0$ is $L$, but $f(x) < L$ for all $x$ in a left neighborhood of $x_0$, is:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = L^{-} $$ 
Similarly for $L^{+}$. However, it is not often used.

Comment: Thanks, was useful

Answer (score 0):

Because $- 0= 0$.

When we say $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = k$. We mean there is a number that is $k$.  $k$ is *ACTUALLY* a *number*.  So that we can find $x$ large enough that the distance between $k$ and the value of $f(x)$ for $x$ values large enough is as small as we like.

But $k$ is a *NUMBER*.  It is true that the function will behave in a way that we can say "the values of $\frac {c}{x^n}$ gets close to $0$ but always negative as $x \to -\infty$" but that is *not* what the *NUMBER* $k$ communicates.  $k$ represents the *actual* number (which need not be any actual value of $f(x)$).  And that *number* is not "some unspecified value that the a little less than $0$".  That *number*  ***IS*** $0$.  $0$ exactly.